# Different between absolute path and logical path

Tags: bash

I am asking this, as I was wondering if they are any similarities at all between absolute path directorty and logical path directory

Comment: Are they identical, is what you meant by versus?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "logical" path includes symlinks traversed. This is as opposed to a "physical" path, which may not contain symlinks. Whether a path is physical or logical is unrelated to whether it is absolute.

On filesystems which do not allow directories to be hardlinked, each directory has exactly one physical path relative to its mount point (a qualifier which allows for bind mounts, multiply-mounted filesystems, and similar corner cases) -- but may have many logical paths.

---

Consider:

```
cd /tmp
mkdir directory
ln -s directory symlink
cd symlink
pwd -P # prints absolute physical path, /tmp/directory (on MacOS, /private/tmp/directory)
pwd -L # prints absolute logical path, /tmp/symlink
```

The *physical* path is `/tmp/directory`. The *logical* path is `/tmp/symlink`. Both these paths are absolute.

---

To demonstrate that whether a path is physical or logical is unrelated to whether it is absolute or relative, consider the following set:

- An example of a *relative physical* path is `./directory`
- An example of a *absolute physical* path is `/tmp/directory`
- An example of a *relative logical* path is `./symlink`
- An example of a *absolute logical* path is `/tmp/symlink`

Comment: fyi: `realpath /bar` will show the real path if the given argument is a logical one [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/realpath.1.html)